# Weird word spacing in latex

Tags: spacing

Why is it so weird spacing like this in LaTeX, how can I remove it? I also noticed that LaTeX auto-shortens words like easily becomes eas-ily.

Look at the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

The code is:

```
 the search engine. With this many choices it is impossible for the user to
 consider them all, and one can easily be overwhelmed. 
  \linebreak
  \linebreak
```

Comment: Thanks, I searched for it but I was unable to find it. And the most rated answer says i should do \linebreak{4} but it doesn't work.

Comment: `\linebreak` says "break the line here and make the broken line end at the right margin".  if (la)tex can't distribute the space in the paragraph sensibly, it puts all the extra space into one line, as has happened here.  what you probably want here is the end of a paragraph, with extra space following it.  to do that, just leave a blank line, then add `\vspace{<dimen>}` to get a specific gap, or `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` to add extra "adjustable" space.

Comment: Thanks Barbara! That worked, I simply change the two \linebreak \linebreak to a blank line and \bigskip